# Modify file opened in Read mode

Tags: file

My file is signed using asymetric cryptography. I open the file in read mode using c language, verify its signature and then I work with that file (read its contents). Is there any possibility of an attack where the attacker (another process) can modify the file after I checked its signature while the file is still opened in read mode?

My platform is mainly Windows 10.